# Return the values of a list of inputs from a module

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I have a module in which I create a list of inputs based on a reactive value: if this value is 3, then 3 `textInput`s are created, etc. Until now, when I needed to return inputs/values from a module, I listed all of the inputs/values in `return()` at the end of the `server` part of my module (see [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicate-bet-modules.html) for more details).

But in this situation, since the number of inputs is not constant, I can't list all of the inputs in `return()`. Therefore, I would like to create a reactive list that I could return.

Consider the example below:

```
library(shiny)

some_things <- c("drat", "mpg", "cyl")
numtextinputs <- length(some_things)

some_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        12,
        lapply(1:numtextinputs, function(x) {
          textInput(ns(some_things[x]),
                    label = some_things[x],
                    value = some_things[x])
        }),
        actionButton(ns("change"), "change inputs")
      )
    )
  )
}

some_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$change, {

    test <- list()
    char_numtextinputs <- as.character(numtextinputs)

    for (x in char_numtextinputs) {
      local({
        test[[x]] <- input[[some_things[x]]]
      })
    }

    return(reactive({ test }) )
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("create_ui", "create ui"),
  uiOutput("ui"),
  verbatimTextOutput("display_changes")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$create_ui, {
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      some_UI("1")
    })
    list_of_variables <- callModule(some_server, "1")
  })

  output$display_changes <- renderText({
    if (exists("list_of_variables")){
      list_of_variables$test()
    }
    else {
      "list_of_variables$test does not exist"
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this example, clicking on "create ui" generates a list of `textInput`s. Note that here, the number of `textInput`s created is constant (I wanted to have a simple example, adding some reactivity in the number of inputs to be created is not very useful).

**Expected result:** after having generated the list of `textInput`s, the user can modify the values in those and click on "change inputs" when he/she has finished. The module should then return the values in the `textInput`s as a vector. The `verbatimTextOutput` is just here to verify that the values are well returned. Note that the answer should work with any number of `textInput`s (this is why I tried lists and loop).

Also asked [on Rstudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/return-the-values-of-a-list-of-inputs-from-a-module/66290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This app will create 3 textInputs in a UI module and return a vector of the textInput values extracted using a server module and display in the UI. Some of this original example has been slightly modified or removed to highlight the answer of returning a vector of values from inputs created in a module.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

some_things <- c("drat", "mpg", "cyl")
numtextinputs <- length(some_things)


some_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        12,
        map(some_things, ~textInput(ns(.x), label = .x, value = .x ))
      )
    )
  )
}

some_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #extract values of all the text boxes without explicitly naming them
  #by using the ids we used to create the textInputs
  test <- reactive({
    map_chr(some_things, ~input[[.x]])
  })

  #return the vector of values from module *note no () are needed after test
  # i.e. return(test) NOT return(test())
  return(test)
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  some_UI("1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("display_changes")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  list_of_variables <- callModule(some_server, "1")


  output$display_changes <- renderText({

    list_of_variables()


  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is not my question. As I said in my post, I know how to  generate a reactive number of `textInput`s but I didn't put it in my post because it would add complexity for nothing. My question is: how can I return the values of the `textInput`s (which are in a module) as a vector? Normally, there is nothing to change in the overall structure of my example but you can modify the `ui` and `server` part of the module.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I updated the answer to show what you just described - returning a vector of textInputs values from a module. I simplified the example to only include the textInput UI and output vector.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a list of reactives for each input instead of a reactive for a whole list? Like in the official example... `list(a = reactive({input$a}), b = reactive({input$b}), ... )`?